# MAth proof questions Open closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ be a subspace with the induced metric. (induced means the metric restricted to elements of $Y$) Let $A$ be a subset of $Y$. Prove the following facts.

If $A$ is closed in $Y$ Then there exist a set $B$ closed in $X$ such that $A = B \cap Y$.

Would this be valid:

The only set '$B$' I can think of that intersects with $Y$ and equals $A$ is the set $B$. So what is there to prove? That it is closed in $X$ and well as $Y$? Isn't it closed automatically in $X$ if it's closed in $Y$?

Comment: Being closed in $Y$ does not imply closed in $X$, e.g. $X=(-1,1)$, $Y=[0,1/2)$, $A=[0,1/2)$ is closed in $Y$ but not $X$. What you ask to prove is essentially the notion of subspace topology: a set $U$ is open in $Y$ iff there exists $V$ open in $X$ such that $U=V\cap Y$.

Comment: IF we can prove that Y is closed in X, would that be an appropriate proof? Is such a proof possible in this problem?

Comment: If $Y$ is closed in $X$, then closed sets of $Y$ are also closed in $X$. Without $Y$ closed in $X$, try $B=\bar{A}$ (closure of $A$ in $X$): $B\cap Y$ is closed in $Y$, contains $A$...

Comment: Oh crap. That was easy. I don't know why I didn't think of closing the set relative to X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually dealing with the equality of the metric topology on $Y$ and the subspace topology on $Y$. If $A$ is closed in $Y$, it means closed in the metric space $Y$. Being the intersection of $Y$ with a closed $B$ in $X$ means that $A$ is closed in $Y$ with its subspace topology.

Assume $A$ is closed in the metric space $Y$ and let $d^Y$ denote the induced metric. This means that given a $y\in Y$, if for each $\epsilon>0$ the ball $B^Y_\epsilon(y)=\{z\in Y\mid d^Y(z,y)<\epsilon\}$ intersects $A$, then $y\in A$. Assume $x\in \bar A\cap Y$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$ the ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ intersects $A$. Can you show that $x\in A$ ?

Conversely, assume $A=B\cap Y$ for some closed $B$ in $X$. You have to show that given some $y\in Y$ such that $y$ is in the closure of $A$ with respect to $d^Y$, this $y$ is in $A$.

Comment: The converse seems a little trickier to prove. What approach would be the most intuitive, you think? And also, where can I learn more about 'equivalence of the metric topology on Y and the subspace topology on Y?

Comment: @Seedof: If $y\in\bar A^Y$ (the $Y$ in this notation means that we take the relative closure), then each ball $B_\epsilon^Y(y)$ intersects $A$. But then also each $B_\epsilon(y)$ intersects $A$, thus also $B$. Can you do the rest?