# Connection properties of open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I am new to connection issues and I would like to know if you can help me solve the following exercises please, it is not clear to me what relationship you have with connection, thank you.

1.-Let (, ) a metric space, ⊂ a subspace with the restricted metric of . Prove that ⊂ is closed in  if and only if it exists ⊂ closed at  such that  = ∩

2.-Let (, ) a metric space, ⊂ a subspace with the restricted metric of . Prove that if  is closed in  then ⊂ is closed in  if and only if it is closed in

[I know this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979748/math-proof-questions-open-closed-sets), but it is that I still do not see topology, I have only seen metric spaces and this comes in the connection part, I would greatly appreciate your help, thank you.

Edit: I have managed to prove the first statement, could you help me with the second one please, or do you think that from the 2nd one you can attack the first one, I would appreciate any advice, please. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: what's your definition of closed sets in metric spaces?

Comment: @Zest, The definition of closed is that $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\bar{A}$

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a definition.

Comment: Well I think this one is:
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, a set is closed if its complement is open, now, a set $U \subset X$ is said to be open if for all $x \in U$ there is an open ball $B_{e}(x)\subset U$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second statement:

$\Rightarrow$) If $A\subset Y$ is closed in $Y$, then $A=F\cap Y$ for some $F\subset X$ closed in $X$, by (1). Since $Y$ is closed in $X$ and the intersection of closed sets in closed, $A$ is closed in $X$.

$\Leftarrow$) If $A\subset  Y$ is closed in $X$, then $A=A\cap Y$ is closed in $Y$ again by (1).

Comment: Could you help me with the first sentence, try to interpret the solution that I put in the sentence, but I cannot conclude anything, what I have is:
$ \Rightarrow $) Suppose 
is closed in space $(X, d_{y})$
where $d_{y}$ denotes the restricted metric.
This means that given $y\in Y$, if for every $\epsilon> 0$ the open ball defined as $B_{Y_{\epsilon}}$ = {$z\in Y | d_{Y} (, ) <\epsilon$} intersects A, then $y\in A$. Suppose $x\in \bar{A} \cap Y$. So, for each $\epsilon> 0$ the ball $B_{\epsilon}$ intersects A.(Here I do not know how to argue if $x\in A$

Comment: @SamuelMartinez You mentioned in your question that you had proved the first statement.